# How do I properly format this object in powershell?

Tags: windows, shell, powershell, command-line, command-line-interface

I'm trying to create an object with information about all the drives that looks something like this:

```
[
  {"letter": "C:", "volumeName": "Disk C", "brand": "INTEL ModelName", "mediaType" : "Fixed hard disk media"},
  {"letter": "D:", "volumeName": "Disk D", "brand": "Seagate ModelName", "mediaType" : "Fixed hard disk media"},
]
```

But the following powershell command produces not only poorly formated results but also an object for each property of the 1st disk instead of putting all the properties of each disk in an object:

```
% {New-Object PSObject -Property @{'caption' =$(wmic logicaldisk get caption $_); 'volumeName' =$(wmic logicaldisk get VolumeName $_); 'brand' =$(wmic diskdrive get caption $_); 'format' =$(wmic diskdrive get mediaType $_);}} | format-list
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply get it with `Get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk` directly instead of using wmic:

```
Get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk | select `
@{N="letter";E={$_.deviceId}},
@{N="volumeName";E={$_.VolumeName}},
@{N="brand";E={$_.deviceId}},
@{N="mediaType";E={$_.Description}}
```

**Results:**

```
letter volumeName brand mediaType              
------ ---------- ----- ---------              
A:                A:    3 1/2 Inch Floppy Drive
C:                C:    Local Fixed Disk       
D:     OST        D:    Local Fixed Disk       
K:     DATA       K:    CD-ROM Disc
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!